# HttpClient POST resolve to domain host IP instead of API IP

Tags: angular, azure, google-chrome, zonejs

### Current behavior

currently i host angular at firebase hosting which has **151.101.1.195**
and my API is located at azure server that has IP **23.98.64.158**

then i send POST request using the following lines in my angular v6.1.7

```
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', `${environment.ApiHost}api/do/something`, token, { headers: this.authenticationService.getAccessTokenHeader(), responseType: "text" });
return this.httpClient.request<any>(req);
```

it suppose to do a OPTIONS Request to my Azure API server at **23.98.64.158** then only POST
but somehow it dit POST, OPTION and then POST. 
Looking at chrome devtool network tab, shows that my request went to firebase ip **151.101.1.195** for the first POST (which is shouldn't) but subsequent OPTION and POST request resolve to correct azure IP **23.98.64.158**

this is my devtool Header General info i grab which show that it is posted to wrong `Remote Address` **151.101.1.195**

```
Request URL: https://someazuresite.azurewebsites.net/api/do/something
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 504 Gateway Timeout (from ServiceWorker)
Remote Address: 151.101.1.195:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

FROM INITIATOR:-
m | @ | zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:2969
-- | -- | --
  | t.scheduleTask | @ | zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:407
  | onScheduleTask | @ | zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:297
  | t.scheduleTask | @ | zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:401
  | e.scheduleTask | @ | zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:232
  | e.scheduleMacroTask | @ | zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:255
  | p | @ | zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1114
  | (anonymous) | @ | zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:3001
  | N.o.(anonymous function) | @ | zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1394
  | (anonymous) | @ | http.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1639
  | e._trySubscribe | @ | Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:42
  | e.subscribe | @ | Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:28
  | e.call | @ | catchError.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:18
  | e.subscribe | @ | Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:23
  | (anonymous) | @ | subscribeTo.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:21
  | i | @ | subscribeToResult.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:11
  | t._innerSub | @ | mergeMap.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:73
  | t._tryNext | @ | mergeMap.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:68
  | t._next | @ | mergeMap.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:51
  | t.next | @ | Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:55
  | (anonymous) | @ | scalar.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:5
  | e._trySubscribe | @ | Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:42
  | e.subscribe | @ | Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:28
  | e.call | @ | mergeMap.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:29
  | e.subscribe | @ | Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:23
  | (anonymous) | @ | kg-fcm-setup.component.ts:64
```

then subsequent request pointed back to correct Azure IP

```
Request URL: https://someazuresite.azurewebsites.net/api/do/something
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 23.98.64.158:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Request URL: https://someazuresite.azurewebsites.net/api/do/something
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: 23.98.64.158:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

### Expected behavior

i should see only call OPTION and POST to  https://someazuresite.azurewebsites.net/api/do/something and resolve to AZURE IP only **Remote Address: 23.98.64.158:443**
why did zone.js starts POST to the wrong firebase IP?

### Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions

### What is the motivation / use case for changing the behavior?

### Environment

````
Angular CLI: 6.1.5
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router, service-worker

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.7.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.7.1
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.7.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.7.1
@angular-devkit/core               0.7.5
@angular-devkit/schematics         0.7.5
@angular/cli                       6.1.5
@angular/pwa                       0.7.5
@ngtools/json-schema               1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   6.1.1
@schematics/angular                0.7.5
@schematics/update                 0.7.5
ng-packagr                         3.0.6
rxjs                               6.3.2
typescript                         2.9.2
webpack                            4.9.2
<pre><code>
Angular version: X.Y.Z
<!-- Check whether this is still an issue in the most recent Angular version -->

Browser:
- [x] Chrome (desktop) version XX
- [ ] Chrome (Android) version XX
- [ ] Chrome (iOS) version XX
- [ ] Firefox version XX
- [ ] Safari (desktop) version XX
- [ ] Safari (iOS) version XX
- [ ] IE version XX
- [ ] Edge version XX
```

For Tooling issues:
- Node version: v8.12.0
- Platform:  windows 10 Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134
````

Answer (score 0):

when I use the HttpClient, i set as a private object in the constructor and then use that object in my functions, in this way:

`constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

request(token ) { 
    return this.http.post(this.URLAPI/any, token);
}`

Maybe this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not Angular related instead domain setup.

It looks like DNS for your domain is changed recently. Just wait for 24-48 hours to see the changes permanently.